# Time zone issue with "Malay Peninsula Standard Time"

Tags: c#, time

I have a program that runs the following code on C#:

```
TimeZoneInfo localZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
string timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(localZone.Id).ToString();
MessageBox.Show("Local Time Zone ID: " + timeZone);
```

When I run this, I got the following exception:

System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: The time zone ID 'Malay Peninsula Standard Time' was not found on the local computer.

I made a slight modification on the code and used this line:

```
TimeZoneInfo localZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
MessageBox.Show("Local Time Zone ID: " + localZone.StandardName);
```

And this time I got no exception, and I got the popup message with the time zone "Malay Peninsula Standard Time"

Why the first fragment of code is not working?

Comment: I'm in Singapore, which uses the same system time zone, and I get the same output as @Grant Winney. Though FWIW, I'm on Win7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time (days), I finally found out what was happening.

Debugging the code, I see that `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` was retrieving the following value:

Malay Peninsula Standard Time

I made some investigation, and found out that all the time zones for the server are stored on this registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\

If you browse through them, you will see that no key is called "Malay Peninsula Standard Time", the value that is for that time zone is "Singapore Standard Time". The whole information for that time zone is the following:

```
ID: Singapore Standard Time
Display Name:      (GMT+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore
Standard Name:           Malay Peninsula Standard Time
Daylight Name:           Malay Peninsula Daylight Time   ***Does Not Have    Daylight Saving Time***
 Offset from UTC:                       8 hours, 0 minutes
 Number of adjustment rules:                          0
```

So, as you see, the ID that I was looking for did not exist, and that's why I got that exception. I renamed the registry key to "Malay Peninsula Standard Time" and the problem was gone.

Comment: excellent solution, its saves my lot of time, to edit registry key search regedit on windows search and go above registry key path

Comment: Editing the registry key for this problem is a horrible idea.  Simply be sure you're passing the `Id` rather than `StandardName`.

Comment: Re-reading the original question, this could only happen if the registry settings for the *current* time zone had been modified in the first place.