# mysql-connector-java-8.0.12 : getting error for 'Malay Peninsula Standard Time' server time zone

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector, tomcat9, tomcat-jdbc

We recently upgraded MySQL from 5.6 to 8. So, as per upgrade instructions,using  **mysql-java-connector(8.0.12)** and new driver class name i.e **com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver** in database url.  But Getting below error only for this time zone **'Malay Peninsula Standard Time'**

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The server time zone value 'Malay Peninsula Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.)
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamicEntityManagerFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
>   ...............
>   ..............
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Malay Peninsula Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)

using below configuration to create connections in tomcat context.xml

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" factory="com.grc.common.EncryptedDataSourceFactory" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000" minIdle="10" name="jdbc/TestDB" password="0df9f21ee02a561fa39f18f5c7581061" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="180" testOnBorrow="true" testOnReturn="false" testWhileIdle="true" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/production1?useSSL=false" username="root" validationInterval="30000" validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>
```

Also, tried with serverTimezone parameter like below, but no luck.

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" factory="com.grc.common.EncryptedDataSourceFactory" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000" minIdle="10" name="jdbc/TestDB" password="0df9f21ee02a561fa39f18f5c7581061" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="180" testOnBorrow="true" testOnReturn="false" testWhileIdle="true" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/production1?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=Malay Peninsula Standard Time" username="root" validationInterval="30000" validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>
```

Comment: That time zone apparently has another name in some systems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589491/time-zone-issue-with-malay-peninsula-standard-time

Comment: @mypetlion, Yes, I saw this post before posting this issue. But I am not allowed to change the registry name at client system. Is there any other solution for this at mysql, tomcat data source configuration level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved myself without changing any registry at OS level. This may help others.

Getting this error since Time zone name with 'Malay Peninsula Standard Time' is not available in MySQL. So as instructed in this [MySQL Documenation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html), downloaded **timezone_2018e_posix_sql.zip** from this [MySQL Timezones](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html) and loaded into MySQL database as instructed. After that added below configuration in my.ini file and restarted the server.

```
default_time_zone=Asia/Singapore
```

Comment: Wouldn't be enough to execute the following MySQL command? `SET GLOBAL time_zone='Asia/Kuala_Lumpur';`